# Issue in notifying using didSet

Tags: ios, swift, didset

I have a collection view with images. Each collection view item has the image & other data associated with them like 'grand_total', 'product_id' etc. Now each collection view item has a button & when I click on it, the values like grand_total etc. associated with that should be stored in an array of dictionary.

And when I click on another collection view item, the values related to it will also be stored in the array of dictionary. So ultimately if I would have clicked on 2 collection view items, all values related to those 2 collection view items will be stored in an array of dictionary like so...

```
[{"remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id”:”4”}, {"remaining_balance”:”1.0”,”shipping_charges”:200, "grand_total”:456,”product_id”:”5”}]
```

Using `didSet` this can be achieved I was suggested but how will I use `didSet` in this scenario that I'm not able to figure out. I'm not so skilled at things hence asking the question...:)

And finally, when I make my API request all values in the array of dictionary will be passed as a parameter like so...

```
func APICallForDetails() {
    let url = "http://myapp/myUrl……”
    let headers = [ "Content-Type"...

    let parameters = [
            "access_token": self.accessToken,
            "seller_id": sellerIdvar,
            “order_data”: allMyData 
            "user_details": myUserDetails
        ]
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: Parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            if let httpResponse = response.response {
                    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                        print(“Something went wrong”)                                
                        }  else if result["success"] as! Int == 1 {
                            print(“SUCCESS!”) }}
```

In the `parameters` section, the parameter `order_data` has the value `allMyData` and `allMyData` should contain `[{"remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id":"4"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a struct or a class  to show data in collectionview. I guess your object struct should look something like this:

```
struct Product {
    let remainingBalance:String
    let shippingCharges:Int
    let grandTotal:Int
    let productId:String

    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any] {
        return ["remaining_balance":remainingBalance, "shipping_charges":shippingCharges, "grand_total": grandTotal, "product_id":productId]
    }
}
```

Again assuming, you have maintained an array of objects, which gets clicked in an array something like this:

```
var clickedProducs:[Product] = []
```

Now, when you are ready to call your API, you can get array of dictionaries like this:

```
let arrayOfProductDict = clickedProducs.map({$0.toDictionary()})
```

I dont think you need `didSet` at all.

Answer (score 0):

"didSet" could help you just in case when you want react to change of array allMyData. You need to add data e.g {"remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id":"4"} to the array somehow like:

```
@IBAction func addInfoAction(_ sender: NSButton) {

     allMyData.append(["remaining_balance":"0.0","shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320,"product_id":"4"])
}
```

To avoid doubles in your array allMyData, consider adding some unique attribute to the orders dictionary.
Like:

```
["orderID":12345,
 "remaining_balance":"0.0",
 "shipping_charges":0,
 "grand_total":320,
 "product_id":"4"]
```

In this case you will be able to check if there is information for the order you want to add in the array or no. And then decide just add the information or update.

May be better to organise your property allMyData as dictionary of dictionaries [String: [String: Any]] In that case if you have order ID, you just put your order dictionary in allMyData using order ID

```
allMyData[orderID] = ["orderID":12345, "remaining_balance":"0.0", "shipping_charges":0, "grand_total":320, "product_id":"4"]
```